# Object doesn't support property or method 'getRootNode' Polymer 2.x Internet Explorer ERROR

Tags: internet-explorer-11, polymer-2.x

I am having  an issue in IE11 and EDGE 14

`Object doesn't support property or method 'getRootNode'`

from webcomponents-hi-sd-ce.js

Any Ideas how to resolve this?

I am serving `es5` code built using `polymer-build`

[image]

I have noticed that the Node.prototype.getRootNode function does exists in my page in ie11. This means that the polyfill is loaded by the time that get to the console and can log something

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'item'
CustomElementInternals.js (261,7)

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getRootNode'
patch-events.js (73,7)

Answer (score 0):

Using compilation for your project you may consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support